# Access Amazon EC2 without private/public keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

How can I access my amazon ec2 instance the same way I access a normal server running SSH?

I would like to type in my Mac terminal: ssh root@[amazon.ip.address]
then the password for root

Instead I have to use these stupid public/private keys that have to live somewhere on my computer.  I use dozens of computers throughout my day.  I don't want to have to carry around my key on a flash drive all day.

Does any one know how I can achieve the above?

Thanks

Comment: Put simply: Switching away from SSH keys to passwords is bad. SSH keys are more secure. This is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended you use password authentication as its susceptible to man in the middle attacks. If you don't want to keep track of your keys you can always use the `ssh-add` command on Linux or something like `puttygen` on Windows.

For example on Linux:

```
ssh-add <your-keyname>
```

To list the keys in your `ssh-agent`

```
ssh-add -l
```

The drawback is there's a limit of number of keys you can add before most ssh servers with basic configuration will start rejecting them. (I believe it's 3). You can workaround this by configuring in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
MaxAuthTries <number of keys you want to try>
```

And if you want to knock yourself out and use password authentication you can simply enable it in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file also:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: That didn't work.. I enabled that in the config and I still can't connect.

Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Comment: Did you enable it on the server?

Comment: And also did you restart the ssh server?

Comment: I did exactly what you said.